# How to loop a mongoosejs result and show it in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have the following code in my controller.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
Appointment.find().then((appointments) => {
    console.log(appointments);
    res.render('adminappointments', { title: 'Admin-Appointments', appointlink: true, layout: 'adminlayout', appointment: appointments });
}, (err) => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
})
```

});

And in my hbs page

```
<tbody>


{{#each appointmentt}}

 <tr>
      <td>{{this._id}}</td>


       <td>{{this.name}}</td>
        <td>{{this.email}}</td>
        <td>{{this.purpose}}</td>
        <td>{{this.clinic}}</td>
        <td>{{this.message}}</td>
        <td>


        <button class="btn btn-small btn-inverse"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button></td>
    </tr>

{{/each}}

</tbody>
```

The table shows no data, but console log is showing the data. Need help.

Comment: in your handlebar its `appointmentt` not `appointment` its a misspell in post or in original code?. check it

Comment: In the code. Got it.